# (Wso2 Api Manager 2.6.0) How to send a list of string as input using mediator?

Tags: api, wso2, mediator, api-manager

(Wso2 Api Manager 2.6.0) How to send a list of string as input using mediator?

I have a Api and my api have a list of string for input.
my api is soap.
I think mediator can help me.
I want a mediator for this api.

for example this is my input:

```
  <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:arr="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetData>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:value>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <arr:string>a</arr:string>
             <arr:string>s</arr:string>
            <arr:string>f</arr:string>

         </tem:value>
      </tem:GetData>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

and this is my output

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <s:Body>
      <GetDataResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
         <GetDataResult>You entered:   a  s  f</GetDataResult>
      </GetDataResponse>
   </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Comment: I find this question pretty confusing. You mention sending list of strings but also a soap apu, which implies that you need XML instead of the list. You are asking multiple things but provide no examples or things you have tried for yourself. Please update the question with examples or scenario's you've worked out.

Comment: @Ludo21South I update my question please check! thank you

Comment: Still a bit confused. API manager is used to publish existing api's or legacy systems to different networks. You now provided a sample input and output, but this does not seem to have anything to do with WSO2 APM, more with the underlying API itself. If that is the case, please create a new question and leave the WSO2 tag out. You might get more response and help.  It also doesn't show what you tried and encountered.